# Stripe with the node-ssl-root-cas library

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, stripe-payments, ca

I am using [node-ssl-root-cas](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas) as I was getting UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE errors whilst connecting to a HTTPS web server.

With the node-ssl-root-cas library, I am able to add the required CA certificates:

```
require('ssl-root-cas')
    .addFile(__dirname + '/rapidssl_1.crt')
    .addFile(__dirname + '/rapidssl_2.crt');
```

However, this prevents Stripe requests from being made in the node app.
I get the following error when making a Stripe request.

```
  rawType: undefined,
  code: undefined,
  param: undefined,
  message: 'An error occurred with our connection to Stripe',
  detail: { [Error: certificate not trusted] code: 'CERT_UNTRUSTED' },
  raw: 
   { message: 'An error occurred with our connection to Stripe',
     detail: { [Error: certificate not trusted] code: 'CERT_UNTRUSTED' } } }
```

When I remove require('ssl-root-cas') Stripe requests succeed but my requests to my HTTPS web service then fail again.

It looks like node-ssl-root-cas doesn't include the required CA certificates for Stripe?